# Effectively save instance attribute with nested multiprocessing Pools/Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two custom Python classes, the first one has a method to make some calculations (using Pool) and create a new instance attribute, and the second one is used to aggregate two objects of the first class and has a method with which I want to send said calculations (also in parallel) in the two first-class objects and correctly save their new instance attributes.

Dummy code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process

class State:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def calculate(self):
        with Pool() as p:
            p.map(function, args)
        new_attribute = *some code that reads the files generated with the Pool*
        self.new_attribute = new_attribute
        return


class Pair:
    def __init__(self. state1:State, state2:State):
        self.state1 = state1
        self.state2 = state2

    def calculate_states(self):
        for state in [self.state1, self.state2]
            p = Process(state.calculate, args)
            p.start()
        return




state1 = State(data1)
state2 = State(data2)
pair = Pair(state1, state2)
pair.calculate_states()
```

The problem is that, as I have found out during my extensive research about the problem, multiprocessing.Process creates copies of the namespace in which the processes work, and the values aren't returned to the main namespace. Setting the process.daemon to True produces an error, because "daemonic processes aren't allowed to have children", which is the same thing that happens if I exchange the Processes by an additional Pool. Using multiprocess (instead of multiprocessing) or concurrent.futures doesn't seem to work either. Additionally, I don't understand how multiprocessing.Queue works and I'm not sure if it could be applied here (I have read somewhere that it could be used).

I would like to do what I am trying to do without having to pass a shared-memory object to the Processes (to write the new_attribute into it and then apply it to the States in the main namespace). I hope someone can point me towards the solution even if I have not provided a working code/reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises from invoking method `calculate` as a new subprocess. You can still compute the new attributes in parallel without doing that by using `map_async` with a *callback* argument.

I have taken your code and provided missing function implementations to demonstrate:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def some_code(data):
    if data == 1:
        return 1032
    if data == 2:
        return 9874
    raise ValueError('Invalid data value:', data)

def function(val):
    ...
    # return value is not of interest

class State:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def calculate(self, pool, args):
        pool.map_async(function, args, callback=self.callback)

    def callback(self, result):
        """
        Called when map_async completes
        """
        new_attribute = some_code(self.data)
        self.new_attribute = new_attribute


class Pair:
    def __init__(self, state1:State, state2:State):
        self.state1 = state1
        self.state2 = state2

    def calculate_states(self):
        args = (6, 9, 18)
        # Assumption is computation is VERY CPU-intensive
        # If there is quite a bit of I/O involved then: pool_size = 2 * len(args)
        # If it's mostly I/O you should have been using multithreading to begin with
        pool_size = min(2*len(args), cpu_count())
        with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
            for state in [self.state1, self.state2]:
                state.calculate(pool, args)
            # wait for tasks to complete
            pool.close()
            pool.join()


# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data1 = 1
    data2 = 2

    state1 = State(data1)
    state2 = State(data2)
    pair = Pair(state1, state2)
    pair.calculate_states()
    print(state1.new_attribute, state2.new_attribute)
```

Prints:

```
1032 9874
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Passing around the Pool object is what I was missing, although in the end I used apply_async, which I didn't know and is very useful. Thanks again!

Comment: When you have a worker function (`state.calculate` in this case) that you want to use to process elements of an *iterable* (`args` in this case) in parallel, `map` or `map_async` might be *in general* preferred to `apply_async` when the *iterable* is large due to the *chunking* the map methods perform (see the *chunksize* argument for the `map` method). `apply_async` in essence is using an implicit *chunksize* value of 1. So `map_async` or `map` can give you superior performance. Just saying.

Comment: I will try out map as well per your comment, because right now I am having problems with zombie tasks. Thanks again!

Comment: Zombie tasks sound like a different issue. I am not sure why you would be getting those.